# Possible outcomes: Poker hands with one ace

Tags: probability

Among the $2598960$ possible $5$-card poker hands, how many will contain at least one ace?

If I do $\mathrm n(\text{number of 5 card hands}) - \mathrm n(\text{no ace})$: The only way to obtain a no ace would be $\binom{2598960}{0} = 1$ Is that right?

Comment: Your title should be more descriptive of your question, @Mef.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This is for all hands with *no* ace. I thought that was the original question.

Take all the aces out of the deck. There are 48 cards remaining.

From these 48 cards, you draw 5 cards to make a poker hand. Thus, there are 48 choose 5 hands, or $\begin{pmatrix} 48 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{48!}{5!(48-5)!}$.

For hands with at least one ace, we just subtract all possible hands with *no* aces from the total number of poker hands.

Comment: 48C5 is the answer ? IE: 1712304?

Comment: Think about it. What is a poker hand? How do we compute how many possible hands there are in a 52 card deck? How does that change if we light all the aces on fire?

Comment: What number did u get as the final answer?

Comment: Note that $\binom{48}{5}$ is for hands with <i>no</i> Ace.

Comment: Nevermind, I am really out of it today. My original answer was what I wanted to post, I just left out a sentence.